# Как вызывается метод не вызываясь?

Tags: c#

Дан код,который сравнивает точки против часовой стрелки.В строчке Array.Sort() есть 2 аргумента в виде массива самих точек и "сравнителя" их.Смутил меня 2-ой аргумент,где создается новый объект класса ClockwiseComparer,где никак не вызывается метод Compare,а просто создается новый объект.Каким образом вызывается этот метод? Прошу сильно меня не пинать т.к изучаю программирование и ООП для меня в новинку.

```
public class Point
    {
        public double X;
        public double Y;

    }
    public class ClockwiseComparer : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            var dot1 = (Point)x;
            var dot2 = (Point)y;
            return Math.Atan2(-dot1.Y, -dot1.X).CompareTo(Math.Atan2(-dot2.Y, -dot2.X));
        }
    }
    internal class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = new[]
            {
                 new Point { X = 1, Y = 0 },
                 new Point { X = -1, Y = 0 },
                 new Point { X = 0, Y = 1 },
                 new Point { X = 0, Y = -1 },
                 new Point { X = 0.01, Y = 1 }
            };
            Array.Sort(array, new ClockwiseComparer());
            foreach (Point e in array)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Для того, чтоб понять "КАК", вам надо сделать что-то сложнее, чем класс с двумя полями. Сделайте класс, который будет что-то требовать, иметь методы, и т.д. Допустим, ваш класс `Point`, сделайте в нем статичный метод `Create`, который будет принимать строку `100,200` и на ее основе создавать сам себя. У вас будет что-то по типу `public static Point Create(string value) { var ... = value.Split(','); .... return new(...); }`, вот что тут происходит вам понятно? Передаем в метод класс `string` и вызываем уже метод этого класса, вот тоже самое и в вашем коде, только там еще интерфейс задействован.

Comment: `Array.Sort` внутри себя вызывает `comparer.Compare`.

Answer (score 5):

Да на самом деле всё просто. Метод `Sort` внутри себя просто вызовет метод `Compare` у переданного класса. Вот и всё. Условно будет так:

```
Sort(array, comparer) {  
    // какая-то логика  
    comparer.Compare(array[i], array[i + 1])
    // какая-то логика  
}
```